# Update java with java?

Tags: deployment, java, auto-update

I was looking around and couldn't find this anywhere, but is there any way to update the JRE through a java application and then to restart said application using the new JRE?

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. I see that it was marked as "not constructive," but how is it that this isn't? Other people might want to know how to update the JRE using their app to ensure everything will work, right? I'm not arguing, I just want a better understanding of how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the JRE from within a running Java app. is not something that is commonly done.

Instead look to [`deployJava.js`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) for ensuring a particular major version of Java is installed, and [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for ensuring a [particular micro-version](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html) is available.

These technologies are both related to launching rich clients (applets and desktop apps.) so if the app. has a GUI [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114205/floating-button-is-awt) it should be 'all systems go'.